# caching data in memory as shared

Tags: caching, memory

I am trying to cache some frequent accessed tables in memory as shared.

Those tables are also not very often updated. thats why I will be fine with that but for example one of the table has over 200.000 rows. Will this be any problem?

Is there anyway or tool to observe occupied space and behaviours of these tables in memory?

Comment: What language/platform? What database?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [memcached](http://memcached.org/) if you want to store object information... there are many clients and the server(s) can be ran on Linux and windows.